# Cannot load WebView: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, library is 64-bit instead of 32-bit

Tags: android, webview, 64-bit

I start an Activity which has android native webView(android.webkit.WebView), I get the following error in 64-bit device.

```
error instantiating provider                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load WebView
at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.loadLibrary(AwBrowserProcess.java:52)

Caused by: org.chromium.base.library_loader.ProcessInitException

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
```

Please provide some valuable suggestions.

Comment: visit this : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=547842

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into the same error when running tests on a remote device in a device farm. It was a Samsung S6 device running Android 6. I don't think either is particularly specific and this issue is likely to happen on various devices and OS versions.

Our automated tests were failing with the same error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:372)
```

These errors have been happening for several days. I managed to connect onto the device interactively and found our app wouldn't start on it. I then checked in Google Play and discovered there were various updates pending, including one for the Android System WebView, which had been last updated 31 weeks ago.

I decided to update that one item and then tried running our app again. Our app now works.

The clue was the discussion in the link provided by @Ironman above
    https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=547842 which included a device that had been upgraded from a 32-bit OS to a 64-bit OS but somehow Google Play was still sending a 32-bit binary of the WebView. No matter... what was key was the problem was related to an old, incorrect version of the binary for the WebView component.

BTW I think the problem surfaced when we updated various components and gradle in our app's gradle configuration. https://github.com/kiwix/kiwix-android/commit/1e03a4ae72f8fe5a9a133913e110add7f3a37631

```
04-12 17:40:09.605  7979  7979 E dex2oat : Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.google.android.webview-1@base.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
04-12 17:40:09.615  7946  7946 W art     : Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/base.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.google.android.webview-1@base.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
04-12 17:40:09.715  7946  7946 E cr_LibraryLoader: Unable to load library: webviewchromium
04-12 17:40:09.715  7946  7946 E WebViewFactory: error instantiating provider
04-12 17:40:09.715  7946  7946 E WebViewFactory: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
-- cut --
04-12 17:40:09.715  7946  7946 E WebViewFactory: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
-- cut --
04-12 17:40:09.725  7946  7946 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/com.google.android.webview-1/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
```

Comment: This is still occurring in the latest gradle and versions. All are occurring in 
Android 7.1.2. 99.99% Xiami and 0.01 in Samsung

Comment: @Killer Thanks for the update. How do you determine the ratio between Xiaomi and Samsung? e.g. is it from Android Vitals or Crashlytics, or from testing you do?

Comment: Probably it would 100% on xiaomi. It is from Crashlytics data.

Comment: No, Mine is all OS 12, I will post my logcat if it helps: @Shubham AgaRwal